# tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits - labels without one hot encoding in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to understand how `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` works.

Description says:

```
    A common use case is to have logits of shape [batch_size, num_classes]
 and labels of shape [batch_size]. But higher dimensions are supported.
```

So it suggests that we can feed labels in raw form for example `[1,2,3]`.

Now since all computations are done per batch I believe the following is possible:

In all cases we assume size of batch equal two.

Case 1 (with one batch):
logit:

```
0.4 0.2 0.4
0.3 0.3 0.4
```

correspoding labels:

```
2
3
```

I am guessing labels might be coded as

```
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
```

Case 2 (with another batch):
logit:

```
0.4 0.2 0.4
0.3 0.3 0.4
```

correspoding labels:

```
1
2
```

I am guessing labels might be coded as (I do not see what prevents us from this coding, unless tensorflow keeps track how it coded before)

```
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
```

So we have two different codings. Is it safe to assume that tensorflow keeps coding consistent from batch to batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real coding happening. The labels are just the position of the `1` in the according one-hot vector:

```
0 -> [1, 0, 0]
1 -> [0, 1, 0]
2 -> [0, 0, 1]
```

This "coding" will be used in every batch.

Comment: Thank you very much! so my labels has to be of certain format? What if my labels are 34, 45, 133 and we have only three classes

Comment: @user1700890 Yes, your labels must be integers between 0 and number_of_classes - 1. If your labels are 34, 45 and 133 you will have to code them as 0, 1 and 2 yourself.